# API for creating/uncompressing zip files, ANSI C compatible and used in Windows applications

Tags: windows, api, c, file-compression

This is a first question on this StackExchange site, please let me know if my question is off-topic, and if so, which of the sites would be more appropriate.

I am looking for an API that can be used with ANSI C on a Windows 7 OS.  I will use it to uncompress files created using WinZip, DynaZip, 7zip.

(I have observed that each of these seem to accommodate compression algorithms created by each other, i.e. 7zip opens/creates files that can be open/created by WinZip which can in turn be open/created by DynaZip)

So far I have tried to compile the offerings from ***[7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html)*** and ***[miniz](https://code.google.com/p/miniz/)*** using an ANSI C compiler in the LabWindows/CVI environment (C99 implementation), but ran into missing header files for both offerings.  I have also looked at the Windows APIs in MSDN, but did not find anything there.  Surprised at that, and wonder if I just was not looking in the right areas.

I suspect either of the offerings from ***7zip*** or ***miniz*** would be perfect, except for the incomplete file distribution.  Insights from others that have successfully built either of these APIs (in a Windows/C99 environment) would be helpful.  Or if there is another approach completely, i.e. another API.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why does it have to be ANSI C?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu - My customer is standardized on ANSI C, and the application with which I will use this API will be ansi C.   If the API is written in C++, or C#, that is not a problem, it just has to have a way for me to link with it, i.e. delivered with .dll, .lib and .h.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [**libarchive**](http://www.libarchive.org/) is the answer, but I'm not sure if it's ANSI C. Though it's portable and works on most POSIX-like systems (including FreeBSD, Linux, Solaris, etc.) and supports Windows, including Cygwin, MinGW, and Visual Studio.

Comment: I will give it a look.  Thanks. Are you aware if there are any links to examples using this library?  I did not see one at the link you gave me.

Comment: https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/Examples

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[LZMA SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html)**.

- cross platform
- ANSI C compatible
- public domain license

You must tell your compiler where to look for headers or copy the headers to standard directories (see [this](http://www.asawicki.info/news_1368_lzma_sdk_-_how_to_use.html)).

Comment: LZMA requires using c++ for uncompressing .zip files according to its author.  ANSI C compatibility seems to end with use only for LZMA compression.